# Codeigniter where condition is blank in $this->query()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am facing very weird condition right now. I wrote a query in CodeIgniter with a WHERE condition like this:

```
$queryps = $this->db->query("SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where workorderno =".$sitecode."");
```

But I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1
>
> SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where
>   workorderno =

Now the weird thing is this the variable `$sitecode` is not blank. When I echo the query, it shows this:

```
SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where workorderno =2
```

But in SQL query, I am getting above error. There is nothing in WHERE condition.

I tried every possible way to find out the reason behind it but I am not able to figure out this. Thanks.

Comment: Check this query on mysql data base in sql query and check column datatypes

Comment: its working in mysql database @LomeshKelwadkar

Comment: $queryps = $this->db->query("SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where workorderno ="'.$sitecode.'" ");    can you check this code

Comment: try SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where workorderno ='2'

Comment: Can you show the code for your model?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need, this must be in your model.

```
<?php

    $this->db->select("SELECT count(workorderno) as total");
    $this->db->from("crm_workorder");
    $this->db->where("workorderno",$sitecode);

    $queryps = $this->db->get();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryps = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(workorderno) AS total FROM crm_workorder WHERE workorderno=$sitecode");
```

And make sure that $sitecode has a value.

**TESTED**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select('count(workorderno) as total');
$this->db->from("crm_workorder");

$this->db->where("workorderno",$sitecode);


$query = $this->db->get();

if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
{
    $row = $query->row_array();
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok try this code. your error will be solve.

```
$queryps = $this->db->query("SELECT count(workorderno) as total from crm_workorder where workorderno ='$sitecode'");
```